# SDL Tridion 2009 SP1: Content Porter 2009 SP1 - It is not possible to change a child Publication into a Parent Publication

Tags: tridion, content-porter-2009

I am trying to install WebForms 2010 into an SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 instance.

I am using the method whereby I rename an existing publication to WebForms and then use Content Porter to import the WebForms Building Blocks into that Publication. However, I am receiving the following error:

"It is not possible to change a child Publication into a Parent Publication"

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Publication you are importing has no BluePrinting context so when you import the complete Publication, Content Porter is trying to remove the BluePrinting context of the existing Publication which is not allowed.

The solution to this will be importing only the contents of the WebForms Publication, so on the import selection, choose Children Only when you select the Publication (don't select the entire package).That way it won't try to update the existing Publication (which doesn't really contain anything you need anyways, you need the TBBs and Schema, not the Publication itself).